# Packing multiple variable into one string

Tags: c++

A stream of chars are sent out to a communication device. For readability purposes, i wrote inidividual configurations as variables:

```
unsigned char a1;
unsigned char a2;
unsigned char a3;
unsigned char a4;
unsigned char a5;
std::string a6;
unsigned char a7;
unsigned char a8;
```

What is the best way to pack it into a variable tightly so that it's aligned perfectly?
Till now I've think of put everything into a `struct`.

**edit**: `struct` doesn't look like a viable option since `struct` doesn't hold `string`, and string is varying in size, although is a one time declared thing. Compiled in GCC

**edit2**: Gonna go with packed `struct` method, but will convert the `string` to a `c_str` first. Until a better answer, this is the way to  be.

Comment: While there is already a correct answer: Which compiler(s) are you using? Unfortunately, the packing is compiler-specific.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the compiler detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ***[packed structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing)***, rather than just a structure would be more appropriate.

EDIT: Ofcourse, you should not use `string` as a part of your structure, It skipped me while answering but as others have pointed out. You should conver `string` to character array using  `str.c_str());` and then store the same in the packed structure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think some other people has point out that the string has to be in c_str first.

Comment: @freonix. defenitely it has to be c string. for cpp string you do not know the internal structure and it is not appropriate to send it to devices directly.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to send std::string to device? string has no fixed size. you should use a6.c_str(), and send all with an array of unsigned char and it's size?

Comment: Hm... the string should be a char array.Sorry bout that

Answer (score 1):

```
struct foo {
   unsigned char a1;
   unsigned char a2;
   unsigned char a3;
   unsigned char a4;
   unsigned char a5;
   .
   .
   .

} __attribute__((packed));
```

GCC specific. Read: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes Also have a look at the `aligned` variable attribute

Or manually insert dummy variables to fillup the places where the compiler may introduce padding.

Answer (score 0):

A simple array of `unsigned char` should be enough. But `struct` is the better way though.

Btw, I don't think you can use `std::string` in the `struct`. You need array of `unsigned char` there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your request but you can use std::ostringstream class to merge all the variables in a single string:

```
std::ostringstream sOutStream;
sOutStream << a1 << a2 << a3 << a4 << a5 << a6 << a7 << a8;
std::string sOutput = sOutStream.str();
```

Comment: Yea and that too, but I was going to do two things at once, trying to go for speed. Doing a serialization seems to drag a bit of more time, but of course, its safer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an object like a `std::string` you'll need to use some sort of serialization and/or protocol. The 'raw' string object will contain typically contain a pointer to the actual string data - and that pointer will be meaningless on the other end of the link. Not mention that the data the pointer points to won't be sent (without some sort of serialization) and that some sort of protocol will be necessary to deal with the variable length data that a `std::string` represents.

I think you may have more to consider than just packing things tightly.

Comment: I was going for the easier way out and trying to cutdown some processing time by doing two things at one.