# Most efficient way of writing byte array for streaming

Tags: c++, buffer

I need to create a byte array that is needed to be stream to another device through UART. There are some fixed parameters that I can fill in before hand but variables such as string is dynamically sized. Right up till now, I've been doing:

```
unsigned char buffer[255];
unsigned char wr_head = 0;
buffer[wr_head++] = 0x01; // and so on
memcpy(&buffer[wr_head], &some_chararray, sizeof(some_chararray));
wr_head += some_chararray;
```

I've experimented with other methods like `std::string` and `std::vector` but I felt that there is much manageable way of writing byte array for streams. Suggestions?

**edit**: Please advice on performance as well because is threaded.

**edit2**: Sorry for lacking of details the first time around. The device is indeed an embedded device. Though some suggested some solution, its not really what I want. Maybe a snippet of my current implementation will clear some confusion:

```
unsigned char buffer[255];
unsigned char wr_head = 0;

buffer[wr_head++] = 0x01; // Set message type
buffer[wr_head++] = 0x30; // message length
memcpy(&buffer[wr_head], &some_chararray, sizeof(some_chararray));
wr_head += some_chararray;
buffer[wr_head++] = CalChecksum;
UartSend(&buffer, wr_head); // Send array to stream out from UART
```

The configuration and setting value is known before hand, provided by the device documentation. This question is related to what I've asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041666/packing-multiple-variable-into-one-string)

Thanks for the effort so far.

Comment: What device are your writing this for?

Comment: Device that communicate through serial port

Comment: Your answer, while correct, is completely unhelpful. You've already specified that this is communicating via UART.

Comment: @Nick: Sorry does it matter what device I'm writing for? I've already specific the device type.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve in this line: `wr_head += some_chararray;`

Comment: @ c-smile: Extending the index so it can track the length written

Comment: @freonix: `wr_head` is unsigned char and `some_chararray` is what?

Comment: @freonix - Why do you think this needs more performance. Surely the UART is not nearly as fast as memcpy, so the comm will take nearly all the time here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ring buffer is a typical solution for problems like these.

I have no idea what kind of device you're on, but I'll just *suppose* that you're writing for some kind of embedded device.  Let's assume that there's some interrupt moving data from the ring buffer to the UART.  This interrupt will call `getc`, other code will call `putc` and `puts`.

```
class RingBuffer {
private:
    static unsigned BUFSZ = 256;
    volatile unsigned char buf[BUFSZ];
    volatile unsigned char read, write;

public:
    RingBuffer() : read(0), write(0) { }

    // Blocks until space is available
    void putc(unsigned int c) {
        while (((write - read) & (BUFSZ - 1)) == 1)
            sleep();
        buf[write++ & (BUFSZ - 1)] = c;
    }

    // Returns -1 if empty
    int getc() {
        if (read == write)
            return -1;
        return buf[read++ & (BUFSZ - 1)];
    }

    // There are faster ways to write this.
    void puts(char *str) {
        for (; *str; ++str)
            putc(*str);
    }
};
```

Typically, you don't want to make the buffer dynamically grow for something like this.  There's lots of room for improvement in the above code, and there are also libraries available for this kind of thing.

This particular implementation also never lets you fill the buffer completely, but the code is simpler as a result.  I probably wouldn't put this code in production, but hopefully it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: `putc()` and `getc()` are called from different threads otherwise it makes no sense. If they called from different threads then the code should have proper sync primitives. Without them all this will produce "interesting" results.

Comment: Are they on different threads or different processors?  This code will work with multithreading but not on multiprocessor systems.  You haven't told us what kind of device it is.

Comment: @ Dietrich: Thanks for the explanation, I've updated the question to be, hopefully, much clearer.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: how this "different threads or different processors" is related to the need of using critical sections here or the like? This code will crash in both cases. Just with different frequencies.

Comment: @c-smile: How would it crash on a uniprocessor system?  Can you give a scenario?  (Assuming one reader, one writer.)

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: it is "threaded" as author told us.

In your getc() function the value of `write` can be changed after `if (read == write)` and before `read++`. 

In general special treatment needs to be made in such cases, see: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/LockFree.aspx for example.

Comment: @c-smile: I don't see how such a scenario would give incorrect results.  The linked article seems to be geared towards multiprocessor systems.  In particular, on a uniprocessor system, I/O reordering is never an issue.

Comment: If getc() is called from an interrupt then you'd probably want to disable the interrupt while updating the buffer in putc().  But like you said, you wouldn't put this code into production without a more complete implementation.

Comment: @Sean: Why is it a problem if `getc` is called in an interrupt?

Comment: @Dietrich: Let's say read == write == 0.  You call putc() from your main code which puts the character in the buffer.  If you don't disable interrupts it's possible for getc() to be called after the character is inserted but before write is incremented.  If that happends, getc() will return -1 instead of returning the character.

Comment: @Sean: That is correct behavior.  The `putc` function hasn't returned yet.  It doesn't violate atomicity of the `getc` and `putc` functions.

Answer (score 0):

If UartSend is a blocking function then you can do just this:

```
void UartSend(byte b) { UartSend(&b, 1); } // sends one byte

UartSend(0x01); // Set message type
UartSend(0x30); // message length
UartSend(some_chararray,sizeof(some_chararray));
```